# How to make post request to get data Laravel Guzzle?

Tags: laravel, api, guzzle

Let say, the Secret Key is **XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX** and md5key is **YYYYYYYY**.
I made a Query String QS
**Qs = “method=RegUserInfo&Key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&Time=20140101123456&Username=DemoUser001”**;

After urlencode I got **q='j4tjorjwarfj3trwise0safrwg2wt4awari0fwjfeoh'**

I made MD5 String for building the signature (QS + md5key + Time + Key):
**s = BuildMD5(QS + “YYYYYYYY” + “20140101123456” + “XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX”);**
I got **s='1234567890abcdef'**

So will get **q=j4tjorjwarfj3trwise0safrwg2wt4awari0fwjfeoh&s=1234567890abcdef**

How to resulting POST method query  (using “Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded”)
by POST to http://xxxxx.com/api/api.aspx

My code is

```
   $param = "q=".$q."&s=".$s;
 
    $client = new Client(['headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        ]]);
    try{
        $response = $client->request('POST','http://xxxxxx.com/api/api.aspx', [
            'query' => [$param],
    ]);
    }catch(ClientException $e){
        $response = $e->getResponse();
        $responseBodyAsString = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        dd($responseBodyAsString);
    }
    
}
```

but I get 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you need to use form_params request option.

```
try{
  $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $your_token]]);
  
  $guzzleResponse = $client->post(
                $api_url, [
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'xxxxx',
                    'key' => 'xxx',
                    'time' => 'xxxx', 
                    'username' => 'xxxxxx'
                ]
            ]);
    if ($guzzleResponse->getStatusCode() == 200) {
         $response = json_decode($guzzleResponse->getBody(),true);
         //perform your action with $response 
    } 
}
catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e){
   // you can catch here 40X response errors and 500 response errors

}catch(Exception $e){
   //other errors 
}
```

know more about [form_params](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params)

Comment: Where can I put my  $param = "q=".$q."&s=".$s; ? I don't think I have any Authorization or token. I have my IP whitelist already.

Comment: We use form_param in case we want to create record right? In case, I only want to get data with POST method.

Comment: put it inside in form_params as array

Comment: we use form_params if asked to send via `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type describes form data that is sent in a single block in the HTTP message body. Unlike the query part which you see in URL in a GET request, the length of the data is unrestricted when in body in form_data

Comment: also you can read [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4007969/9471283)

Comment: Oh.. I got it clear now. Thank you.